# UserInRole just doesn't seem to work in MVC 5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 demo application where I want users to be thrown to different menu pages on login. I am using ASP.NET Identity tables and created users and put them in roles. I created a controller for each AdminMenu and UserMenu with an Index action that points to corresponding views.

When I put a breakpoint my code in the Login post method skips over the UserInRoles section to the return View () all the way to the end, sending me back to the login page. I tried other approaches using rolesArray = Roles.GetRolesForUser(). What am I doing wrong?

```
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
        if (user != null) {
            await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);

            if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminMenu");
            }
            if (User.IsInRole("User")) {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "UserMenu");
            }
        } else {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
    //return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
}
```

Comment: `skips over the UserInRoles section` by this, are you saying that neither of the previous `return`s are being called? Just trying to clarify the problem.

Comment: exactly. the code goes straight to the return View() at the end. I read somewhere that you have enable role manager in web.config. I did this as well. Still no luck.

Comment: Try this: while stepping through your code, stop at the line `if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))`. Hover over "User" and look into the related "Roles". Tell me what you see there! [FYI - I'm doing this by memory, so I'm assuming that you can traverse into the Roles there.]

Comment: Sorry here's I put in web.config.
<roleManager enabled="true"></roleManager>

Comment: thanks statue: it says:

Comment: Role {Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole} Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole
  Id "1" string
  Name "admin" string
so it looks like the user role is there and the code is catching it, why won't the next line execute? It doesn't make sense. I just created a branding new MVC 5 app also just to make sure there are no code conflicts elsewhere.

Comment: Ha!! change `(User.IsInRole("Admin"))` to `(User.IsInRole("admin"))`, maybe?

Comment: I did use "admin" lowercase. Sorry that code above was from my actual project where I had used "Admin" as the role. In the new demo project I created, I changed the role and code to "admin" to avoid case issues. Still no luck!

Comment: Darn. Does it get to the line `return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminMenu");` ever? put a breakpoint on _that_. You need to find the true source of your issue. Maybe it's somehow related to `async Task<ActionResult>`; I haven't played with MVC5 before. Look into "MVC 5 async RedirectToAction"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899204/mvc4-net-4-5-async-action-method-does-not-redirect see here?

Comment: Bingo! Is that other task async? If not, there's your issue!!

Comment: I am sorry which other task are you asking is async?

Comment: `RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminMenu");` The action called here (The admin action of hte AdminMenu Controller) is not async (or so I'm guessing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably your issue:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminMenu");
```

My guess is that the method called is not async.

See [MVC4 .NET 4.5 async action method does not redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899204/mvc4-net-4-5-async-action-method-does-not-redirect) for reference

Comment: Ok I tried but I need to add "await"? What am I awaiting SignInSync? 
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: I have 0 idea how async/await works. I have had 0 experience in it. I wish I could help from here, but I can't.

Comment: Ok this is a good reason to abandon MVC for me at this point. For two months I have struggled to learn it and have a nice working project but I keep hitting blocks. There is just not enough code base and guidance on it. I am really sorry. Maybe webforms with the old membership model is the best option. This project is due in 2-3 months and I just dont have the depth of skills and knowledge. Working with Identity has been a highly frustrating experience. Nothing out of the box (forgot password, secret question etc). Who wants to reinvent all that. Sorry for the rant. And thanks for your help.

Comment: Gah!!! No!!! I came from ASP.NET WebForms. I'll never go back. If you need more concentrated help, email me. StachuKorick@gmail.com. Let's talk. I'd hate to see someone go TO WebForms. Yuck.

Comment: At the very least, try out MVC 4. MVC 5 is brand new, and has lower documentation. The user control system is entirely different than from MVC 4, so that is still sort of a work in progress, as well.

Comment: Ok thanks will connect! Hate to go back to WebForms too. But hitting too many roadblocks.

Comment: @SKale: Are you using VS2013 or VS2012. I noticed that even with the upgraded web tooling for VS2012 to support the new MVC5 stuff, you don't get project templates for things like Identity. However, if you start a new Identity project in VS2013, it scaffolds all the models, controllers and views you need for authentication, account creating, password reset, etc.

Comment: I know it scaffolds all the models. The code in the scaffolded controller is what I tried to modify and I wouldn't work due to the async method as pointed out by status. Below is the code that eventually fixed my problem, thanks to my friend and colleague who  helped me with it:

Answer (score 2):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);

                if (await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id.ToString(), "Admin"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminMenu");
                }
                if (await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id.ToString(), "User"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "UserMenu");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Neat! Glad you found your answer; this should come in handy later for me at some point! :)