# How can I redirect to an action using Task in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Asynchronous controller implementation as follows,

```
public Task<ActionResult> UpdateUser(ProfileModel model)
{
   return Task.Factory.StartNew(showMethod).ContinueWith(
         t =>
         {
              return RedirectToAction("ViewUser","UserProfile");
         });
}
```

However I am unable to redirect to the action as I am keep on getting the error,

**Cannot implicitly convert type,** `System.Threading.Taska.Task<Sytem.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult>` **to** `System.Threading.Taska.Task<Sytem.Web.Mvc.ActionResult>`

However I really want to redirect to the mentioned Action, how can I do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the return type of `UpdateUser` action from `Task<ActionResult>` to `Task<RedirectToRouteResult>`

```
public Task<RedirectToRouteResult> UpdateUser(ProfileModel model)
{
  return Task.Factory.StartNew(showMethod).ContinueWith(
    t => {
      return RedirectToAction("ViewUser","UserProfile");
  });
}
```

Or you could explicitly set the generic type argument of `ContinueWith` method with `ActionResult`, like this:

```
public Task<ActionResult> UpdateUser(ProfileModel model)
{
  return Task.Factory.StartNew(showMethod).ContinueWith<ActionResult>(
    t => {
      return RedirectToAction("ViewUser","UserProfile");
  });
}
```

Comment: I dont have a simple thinking.You have

Answer (score 11):

For people who come here looking for an answer, the newer versions of .NET make things simpler. Use the keyword `async` in the definition of the method and you can clear up the body.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateUser(ProfileModel model)
{
   return RedirectToAction("ViewUser","UserProfile");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for updating :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899204/mvc4-net-4-5-async-action-method-does-not-redirect):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model) {
    //You would do some async work here like I was doing.

    return RedirectToAction("Action","Controller");//The action must be async as well
}
public async Task<ActionResult> Action() {//This must be an async task 
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I can't Use async Keyword, I am using .NET 4.0

Comment: @TBA you want use just async?

Comment: http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2012/01/09/evolution-of-async-controller-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: That exactly I am doing in ASP.NEt 4.0 we don't have async and await kewords, it is available in c# 5. And if you refer that link, I am using exactly the same method as for MVC 4.

Comment: see above link that send in comment.

Comment: "The action must be async as well"... this comment in source code help me a lot