# Use of Redirect in Async and Await Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I am facing a problem, I am not able to redirect to some another page by using the await call.

I have been searching for two days but i am not getting the solution. Following is my code:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
 {
      try
      {
          if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
          {
               Response.Redirect(returnUrl, false);
          }
      }
 }
```

Calling Method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GotoLogin()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await Login("/myhome");
    }
}
```

Comment: This link will solve your problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899204/mvc4-net-4-5-async-action-method-does-not-redirect

Comment: @Kaptan Thanks for the reply. I have already tried this tomorrow.

Comment: Apparently if you are redirecting in an async method then the redirect action must also be awaitable. I went around it and because I am using my action through ajax so returned redirectUrl string to ajax and used window.location.href to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to direct the user to the "myHome" controller? try RedirectToAction,

```
return RedirectToAction("myHome", "Home", new { area = "Home"});
```

Comment: Await Method mentioned by @Nimit Joshi,But you written normal RedirectToAction()!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!