# Doesn't Redirect to ForgotPasswordConfirmation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

```
[Authorize]
         public class AccountController : Controller
         {
       [AllowAnonymous]
             public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
             {
                 ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                 return View();
             }

             //
             // POST: /Account/Login
             [HttpPost]
             [AllowAnonymous]
             [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
             public async Task<ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
             {
                 if (ModelState.IsValid)
                 {

                     // find user by username first
                     var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);

                     if (user != null)
                     {
                         var validCredentials = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);

                         // When a user is lockedout, this check is done to ensure that even if the credentials are valid
                         // the user can not login until the lockout duration has passed
                         if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
                         {
                             ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("Invalid credentials. Please try again, or contact
 support", 60));
                         }
                         // if user is subject to lockouts and the credentials are invalid
                         // record the failure and check if user is lockedout and display message, otherwise,
                         // display the number of attempts remaining before lockout
                         else if (await UserManager.GetLockoutEnabledAsync(user.Id) && validCredentials ==
 null)
                         {
                             // Record the failure which also may cause the user to be locked out
                             await UserManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id);

                             string message;

                             if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
                             {
                                 message = string.Format("Invalid credentials. Please try again, or contact support", 60);
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 int accessFailedCount = await UserManager.GetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id);

                                 int attemptsLeft = (5 - accessFailedCount);

                                 message = string.Format("Invalid credentials. Please try again, or contact support.", attemptsLeft);
                             }

                             ModelState.AddModelError("", message);
                         }
                         else if (validCredentials == null)
                         {
                             ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid credentials. Please try again, or contact support.");
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);

                             // When token is verified correctly, clear the access failed count used for lockout
                             await UserManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id);

                             return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                         }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("Invalid credentials. Please try again, or contact
 support", 60));
                     }
                 }
                 // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
                 return View(model);
             }

       [HttpPost]
             [AllowAnonymous]
             [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
             public async Task<ActionResult ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
             {
                 if (ModelState.IsValid)
                 {
                     var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                     if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
                     {
                         // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                         //ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user either does not exist or is not confirmed.");
                         return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                         var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account",
                         new { UserId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

                         string Data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/documents/email_password_reset.txt"));

                         AspNetUser oUser = dbPortal.AspNetUsers.Find(user.Id);
                         // can't use string.format becuase of CSS                
                         Data = Data.Replace("{0}", oUser.Name);  // user name
                         Data = Data.Replace("{1}", callbackUrl); // URL to click
                         Data = Data.Replace("{2}", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()); // copyright year
                         await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", Data);
                         return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
                     }
                 }

                 // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
                 return View(model);

             }

             //
             // GET: /Account/ForgotPasswordConfirmation
             [AllowAnonymous]
             public async Task<ActionResult ForgotPasswordConfirmation()
             {
                 return View();
             }
     }
```

the above should redirect user to ForgotPasswordConfirmation when entered theit email. instead it sends the user to login with the following url

```
Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FForgotPasswordConfirmation
```

i changed according to the duplicate post

i cannot figure out why

Comment: nope! it doesn't work and also "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread."

Answer (score 0):

There are issues if and when you have an async method redirecting to a synchronous method.  Try changing your ForgotPasswordConfirmation() method to async:

```
public asycn Task<ActionResult> ForgotPasswordConfirmation()
```

Also, see this:  [MVC4 .NET 4.5 async action method does not redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899204/mvc4-net-4-5-async-action-method-does-not-redirect)

Comment: nope! it doesn't  work  and also "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread."